# How could I upgrade to OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel, opengl, mesa

**SOULUTION:** Executing the command that doug provided in the comments worked for me `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 ./cascadeur`

I want to run a program called Cascadeur on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS machine.

When I try to run it it displays de following:
**Cascadeur requires OpenGL version 3.3**

[image: 1]

The output produced by the command `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` is the following:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

From the [intel support webpage](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/96551/graphics/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-620.html) we know that it supports OpenGL 4.4

How should I proceed?

Comment: This is the nonsense of OpenGl in mesa. Very confusing.. You'll need to either get your app to adjust & become 'context-aware'. Or you can override the Version String using a value up to your core version. For this app maybe just set the env variable for version   at 3.3 (your core is 4.6. ) To try run this in a terminal, replace xxxxx with command to open app. `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 xxxxx`

Comment: The command that you provided worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: The program probably uses Compatibility Profile, but Intel only supports Core Profile for 3.x stuff.